# Using PyMC to obtain the posterior for the parameters of a parametric model?

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, markov-process, naive-bayes, pymc

I am a newbie with **pyMC** and I want to program an **MCMC** sampling for a complicated problem. I have a function given by in the following:

$$g(r,c,\theta_1,\theta_2)=\frac{\delta_c}{\Sigma x^2}\log{\frac{x}{2}}$$

The parameter $\Sigma$ and $\delta_c$ and $x$ are given by

$$\Sigma(z)=\frac{const*z+\sqrt z}{(1+z)^2}$$ 
$$\delta_c=\frac{c}{\log(1+c)-c}$$
$$x=\frac{c\sqrt{\theta_1^2+\theta_2^2}}{r}$$

The free parameters which I would like to find their posterior probabilities are $r$, $c$ and $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$, while for $r$ the prior is **exponential**, $c$ has **lognormal** prior and $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ have **uniform** priors. My **main problem** is how to define the model, because for each of point in data set I have a probability distribution for parameter $z$ which I would like to **marginalize** over and I don't know how it should be done.
 I have written so far the following piece of code, I have written a **class** for $g$ :

```
import pymc as pm
import g_class
import numpy as np
import math
import random
from scipy.stats import expon
data=np.loadtxt('test.cat') #my data
for i in range(len(data[:,0])):
if (i<1):
    theta=np.array([data[i,0],data[i,1]])
    observed_g=np.array([data[i,2],data[i,3]])
else:
    theta=np.vstack((gal_pos, np.array([data[i,0],data[i,1]]))) 
    observed_g=np.vstack((observed_g, np.array([data[i,2],data[i,3]]))) 

z_pdf=np.loadtxt('pdf.z.dat') #probability distribution of z in the given range
z=np.arange(0,1.5,0.001)

@pm.stochastic(dtype=np.float, observed=False, trace=True)
def thata1(value=235,t1_l=210,t1_h=270):
    if ((value>t1_h) or (value<t1_l)):
       return -np.inf
    else:
       return -np.log(t1_h-t1_l+1)        

@pm.stochastic(dtype=np.float, observed=False, trace=True)
def theta2(value=340,t2_l=320,t2_h=360):
    if ((value>t2_h) or (value<t2_l)):
       return -np.inf
    else:
       return -np.log(t2_h-t2_l+1) 


r=10*pm.Exponential('r', beta=10)


@pm.deterministic  #
def sigma(value = 1, r=r): 
   if r < 10**15:
       return .09
   else:
       return .06

cExpected = (r/10)**(-.1) # parameter c and r related via this formula, I use this to compute exoected value for log(c)
conc = pm.Lognormal("concentration", cExpected, sigma)
#model
@pm.deterministic( name='g', observed=True, trace = True )
def g(r=r,c=conc,z=zh,pos=[thata1,thata2],theta):
    nfw = g_class.g(r=r,c=conc,z=zh,pos=[thata1,thata2])
    value1=0;value2=0
    n=theta[0]
    ID=[i for i,l in enumerate(data) if n in l]
    for i in range(len(z)):
        g1,g2,mag=g_class.getG( theta, z[i])
        value1+=g1*z_pdf[ID,i]/sum(z_pdf)#first component 
        value2+=g2*z_pdf[ID,i]/sum(z_pdf)
    return np.array([value1,value2])


std_dev = pm.Normal('tau', mu=0.0 , 0.3)
#likelihood
obs = pm.Normal("obs", mu=g, tau=1./std_dev**2, value=observed_g, observed=True)
```

The problem is that when I define my model as **Deterministic** and use observation to construct the model, I get the error message that `theta` is not defined properly as a **parent**. I am wondering, how could I include `theta`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just not listing theta in your method parameters? It's not a stochastic variable so I don't think it would be something that pymc would know to pass in when it samples from your deterministic function.